# Trigger build when non-source files change

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lua, cmake

Using CMAKE I added a custom command top copy LUA files from the source directory to the output directory when they are changed. However this command is only fired when Visual Studio decided to build a project (even though I used PRE_BUILD for the custom command). Visual Studio only decides to build when a source file (c++ in this case) changes so when I only change LUA files they are not added to the output directory.

Now in Visual Studio I can change the 'Item Type' in the property pages of the LUA files from 'Does not participate in build' to 'Text'. In that case Visual Studio does trigger a build when only the LUA files change. So how do I make sure that CMAKE assigns the correct Item Type to LUA files? (Or are there other solutions?)

The relevant parts of CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(LUA_Sources
  "lua/initialization.lua")

SOURCE_GROUP("lua" FILES ${LUA_Sources})

ADD_LIBRARY(engine 
  ${LUA_Sources})

foreach(LuaFile ${LUA_Sources})
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET engine
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS    -E 
      copy_if_different ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LuaFile} ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile})
endforeach()
```

===========================

For reference the solution, closely inspired by Angew was

```
SET(LUA_Sources
  "lua/initialization.lua")

SOURCE_GROUP("lua" FILES ${LUA_Sources})

set(LUA_Outputs "")
foreach(LuaFile ${LUA_Sources})
  list(APPEND LUA_Outputs ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile})   
endforeach()

add_custom_target(
  lua ALL
  DEPENDS ${LUA_Outputs}
  COMMENT "Copying LUA files"
  VERBATIM
)

foreach(LuaFile ${LUA_Sources})
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET lua
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS    -E 
      copy_if_different ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LuaFile} 
endforeach()
```

I had to switch things around a bit because else the files would not always be copied if they were newer. Probably because of the OUTPUT directive in ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND instead of the TARGET directive that I use now.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your CMakeLists

Comment: @Angew done, I hope this helps I didn't think that would be too relevant.

Comment: I think your solution has a mistake. Shouldn't the 2nd last line be
`copy_if_different ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LuaFile} ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the CMakeList excerpt is complete and the `engine` target is only supposed to serve as a placeholder to copy the Lua sources, then you're approaching the problem the wrong way. You should use a custom command + custom target combination instead, like this:

```
set(LUA_Sources
  "lua/initialization.lua")

source_group("lua" FILES ${LUA_Sources})

set(LUA_Outputs "")
foreach(LuaFile ${LUA_Sources})
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS -E copy_if_different
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LuaFile}
      ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile}
  )
  list(APPEND LUA_Outputs ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/${LuaFile})
endforeach()

add_custom_target(
  engine ALL
  DEPENDS ${LUA_Outputs}
  COMMENT "Copying LUA files"
  VERBATIM
)
```

This CMakeList creates a custom command to copy each LUA file, and then a custom target which will drive those custom commands by depending on their outputs. Now dependency tracking will work fine.

Comment: The file is not complete. Engine is actually an existing target that also contains a lot of normal code files. I put it in the engine project so that in Visual Studio the LUA files appear in the solution explorer in the right position under the engine project. However let me see if I can adapt your example :).